# how to sum the floors of ratios n/k when prime factorization of n is known

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

According to [@harald-hanche-olsen](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/895195/sum-of-floor-of-ratios) the sum of the floors of ratios of $n/k$ is approximately:

$$n(\ln n-1-\ln2)<\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}\Bigl\lfloor \frac nk\Bigr\rfloor<n\ln n.$$

If the prime factorization of $n$ is known (that is, if $n=\Pi_i{k_i^{\alpha_i}}$), can a closer approximation be obtained?

In my case the exact value of $n$ is not important, just the accuracy of the sum of the floors of the ratios.  One approach is to let $n=\Pi^p_i{i}$ so the the first $p$ sums would be exact (equal to $nH_p$ where $H_p$ is the $p^{th}$ harmonic number) and the approximation is needed only for:

$$
\sum_{k=p+1}^{n-1}\Bigl\lfloor \frac{\Pi^p_i{i}}k\Bigr\rfloor
$$

The reduction in the range is marginal using this approach:  it can be expressed as:
$$nH_p+n(\ln n-1-\ln2)-p(\ln p-1-\ln2)\le\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}\Bigl\lfloor \frac nk\Bigr\rfloor\le nH_p+n\ln n-p\ln p.$$

Other optimizations may be possible. For example:

If $n=p^{2^k}$ then $n\Pi_{i=0}^k(1+p^{-2^i})$ sums for all combinations of factors from $p^0$ to $p^{2^k}$

If $n=4!=24$ then $$\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}\Bigl\lfloor \frac nk\Bigr\rfloor=12+8+6+\Bigl\lfloor \frac {24}5\Bigr\rfloor+4*(6-5)+3*(8-6)+2*(12-8)+1*(24-12)$$ So the biggest region of uncertainty for a factorial $f!$ lies between $f<k<(f-1)!$.  Furthermore we have $$((f-1)!-1)((f-1)!-f-1) < \sum_{k=f+1}^{(f-1)!-1}\Bigl\lfloor \frac nk\Bigr\rfloor < f((f-1)!-f-1)$$

### Edit

The answer should be in the form of:

Given:

$$
a_v <= \sum_{k}^{v-1}\Bigl\lfloor \frac{v}k\Bigr\rfloor <= a_v+\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{v})\\
a_u <= \sum_{k}^{u-1}\Bigl\lfloor \frac{u}k\Bigr\rfloor <= a_u+\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{u})
$$

Conclusion: a method exists to compute $a_{uv}$ such that:
$$
a_{uv} <= \sum_{k}^{uv-1}\Bigl\lfloor \frac{uv}k\Bigr\rfloor <= a_{uv} + \xi \text{ where } \xi << \mathcal{O}(\sqrt{uv})
$$

Comment: You actually *don't* need to share your work for a question like this. In this case we'd like to see motivation for why a closer approximation should be attainable.

Comment: @Zach466920 I provided a suggested approach as an example. Does that help?

Comment: If you use the formula from [achille hui's comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/895195/sum-of-floor-of-ratios#comment1847974_895195) over there, you get something with an $O(\sqrt{n})$ error. Would that be sufficiently precise for your aims?

Comment: As mentioned above, you can bring down the margin to $O(\sqrt{n})$. Would that be good enough for your purposes?

Comment: @DanielFischer I had overlooked the significance of that answer.  It sufficies in that it places a limit on an acceptable maximum error.  I'm less interested in asymptotic precision as n approaches infinity, and more interested in finding a value n that is $\mathcal{O}(d)$ but with an estimate for $\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}\Bigl\lfloor \frac nk\Bigr\rfloor$ that is more precise than $\sum_{k=2}^{d-1}\Bigl\lfloor \frac dk\Bigr\rfloor$.  However, computing the true value may not be as daunting as I had expected.

Answer (score 4):

**Asymptotic Estimate**

First, we have
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac nk=n\log(n)+\gamma n+\frac12+O\left(\frac1n\right)\tag{1}
$$
Using Riemann Sums, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\left\{\frac nk\right\}\frac1n
&=\int_0^1\left\{\frac1x\right\}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_{\frac1{k+1}}^{\frac1k}\left(\frac1x-k\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left[\log\left(\frac{k+1}k\right)-\frac1{k+1}\right]\\[9pt]
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}[\,\log(n)-(H_n-1)\,]\\[12pt]
&=1-\gamma\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

---

**Bounding the Error in $\boldsymbol{(2)}$**

We will consider three classes of intervals:

1. $\left[\frac n{k+1},\frac nk\right]$ where $k\lt\sqrt{n}$.
2. $\left[\frac n{k+1},\frac nk\right]$ where $k\ge\sqrt{n}$ which contain an integer.
3. $\left[\frac n{k+1},\frac nk\right]$ where $k\ge\sqrt{n}$ which don't contain an integer.

There are fewer than $\sqrt{n}$ intervals of class 1.

The integers contained in the intervals of class 2 must be at most $\sqrt{n}$. Thus, there are at most $\sqrt{n}$ intervals of class 2.

For all intervals of class 1 and 2,
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\frac1n\left\{\frac{n\vphantom{1}}k\right\}-\int_{\frac kn}^{\frac{k+1}n}\left\{\frac1x\right\}\,\mathrm{d}x\right|
&\le\int_{\frac kn}^{\frac{k+1}n}\left|\left\{\frac{n\vphantom{1}}k\right\}-\left\{\frac1x\right\}\right|\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&\le\frac1n\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$

For intervals of class 3 and $\frac kn\le x\le\frac{k+1}n$
$$
0\le\left\{\frac{n\vphantom{1}}k\right\}-\left\{\frac1x\right\}\le\left\{\frac n{k\vphantom{+}}\right\}-\left\{\frac n{k+1}\right\}=\frac n{k(k+1)}\tag{5}
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1n\left\{\frac{n\vphantom{1}}k\right\}-\int_{\frac kn}^{\frac{k+1}n}\left\{\frac1x\right\}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_{\frac kn}^{\frac{k+1}n}\left(\left\{\frac{n\vphantom{1}}k\right\}-\left\{\frac1x\right\}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&\le\frac1{k(k+1)}\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
Summing the contribution from intervals of class 1 and 2, using $(4)$, and the contribution from intervals of class 3, using $(6)$,we get
$$
\left|\sum_{k=1}^n\left\{\frac nk\right\}\frac1n-\int_0^1\left\{\frac1x\right\}\,\mathrm{d}x\right|\le\frac3{\sqrt{n}}\tag{7}
$$

---

**Final Result**

Combining $(1)$, $(2)$, and $(7)$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n\left\lfloor\frac nk\right\rfloor
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac nk-\left\{\frac nk\right\}\right)\\
&=n\log(n)+(2\gamma-1)n+O(\sqrt{n})\tag{8}
\end{align}
$$
Subtracting $n+1$, we get
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}\left\lfloor\frac nk\right\rfloor
=n\log(n)-2(1-\gamma)n+O(\sqrt{n})}\tag{9}
$$

Comment: So, by extension, for $l=mn$, we have: $$mn \text{log}(mn)-2(1-\gamma)mn+\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{mn})=\\m(n\text{log}(n)-2(1-\gamma)n+\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n}))-m\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n})+\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{mn})+mn\text{log}(m)$$.  Is there a more elegant way to write that?

Comment: @zQAycX: Why not just stay with the part before the $=$ sign?

Comment: So as a sequence, something like $$a_1=2(\gamma-1)\\a_i=a_{i-1}i+(i^2-i)\text{log}i$$ with each term assumed to have an error of $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{i})$.

Comment: @zQAycX: what are the $a_i$?

Comment: The $a_i$ are successive approximations.  I think my error term is incorrect in my last comment: it should be $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{i!})$.  I fear that the numbers grow large quickly and the error term starts off high in terms of percentage and converges to its asymptotic value slowly. For example $\sqrt{1!}/1=100\%$; not sure off the top of my head when $\sqrt{i!}/i!$ reaches 1%.

Comment: Successive approximations to what? Evidently, you are considering another problem to which you are applying the answer to this question. Perhaps if you explained the actual problem, it might help. This is what is referred to as **context**.

Comment: I knew that would cause confusion as soon as I logged out.  I believe I have used the word successive as per its dictionary definition.  I also believe that the word approximation is used fairly though a good thesaurus would suggest "term" instead.  The noun phrase is thus correct as per the english language dictionary not a math dictionary. $$ $$ I could make an argument that since my original question concerns numbers that are products, the phrase is also mathematically sound, albeit not a very good **successive approximation** since knowing the factorization does not improve the estimate.

Comment: The question remains: successive approximations to what?

Comment: I've edited the question to indicate the form of answer that will be accepted.  Your approach satisfies the part identified as "given", but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @zQAycX: Running simulations, between $160000$ and $250000$, the standard deviation of the values is about $17$ when considering only squares for $n$, and around $21$ when considering all $n$. The values are a bit smaller, but not what I would call $\ll$. I don't think we are going to get the kind of estimate for the error you are looking for.

Comment: You may be right and thanks for the simulation results.  (I assume you partitioned the errors according to $n$ and $n^2$ and compared the standard deviation of the two partitions).$$.$$ As a counter argument, let's assume a function $X(u,v)$ exists that computes an estimate with an error term $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{uv}/v)$.  I argue your approach is equivalent to $x(n,n)=X(n \times n,1)$ and that's why there is no statistical difference.  I apologize if this  is not worded well.

Comment: I am not sure what the definition of "$\ll$" is, but the edited question seems to be asking to find $a_{u,v}$, which, if we set u=v=n, requires $$\left|\,\sum_{k=2}^{n^2-1}\left\lfloor\frac{n^2}k\right\rfloor -a_{n,n}\,\right|= o(n)$$ The variance in the sum seems to preclude finding a nicely behaved $a_{u,v}$, that is, one that doesn't bounce around erratically.

Comment: Actually, although the maximum error of the function given in my answer is $O(\sqrt{n})$, the standard deviation of the errors is $O(\sqrt[\large4]{n})$, which does not preclude an error of order $O(\sqrt{n})$.